# Reason for angular drift of gyro

Tags: noise, gyroscope, drift

actually I am working with gyroscope and read in datasheets and documents about the angular drift.
I am searching for the explanation what it is caused by.
I read there are tow main reasons for random walk: bias stability and white noise.
Why/how can it be described precisely in datasheet that angular random walk has a specified deg/hr?
Why is it not a stochastic process toggeling around zero degree becuase especially white noise has in long term an average of zero.
Does the rms cause this drift?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Don't think your question is anything to do with software - try posting here https://engineering.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you are right.